# Code-First Entity Framework Relationship Always Null

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to set up a one-to-many relationship using .NET Core with Entity Framework using Code-first.

I have two tables: Company and User, with Company having many users. Both tables return data in all columns except for the relationship objects.

Both the Company and User ICollection objects are always null for any request. I have tried fluent mapping with:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<Company>(s => s.Company)
            .WithMany(s => s.User)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.CompanyId);
```

Here are my class objects:

[image: User]

[image: Company]

And here is my database mapping:

[image]

I have verified with inner join that User.CompanyId=1 && CompanyId=1 returns results in the database, but still the Company object on user is null. I've tried renaming CompanyId (FK) to Company_CompanyId, playing with variations of the entity framework attributes, etc to no avail.

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To load related data in [EF core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) you need to use `Include` method as part of your query:

```
var user= context.Users.Include(u=>u.Company).FirstOrDefault(u.UserId==1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple solution. I am used the drag n drop approach with Linq to Sql which doesn't require Include(), so this is new to me but an easy fix.

Comment: You're welcome, Yes, I know the feeling, the issue is EF Core still doesn't support lazy loading