# When I take information from a database object, I get null, such as Car.Color = null

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

I had mistake, but does not understand where. When I`m add to my database object they saved correct, unfortunately not equals my image, maybe it`s my mistake. I need hint to where look. For the sake of simplicity, I will reduce my case to a car and its color, where each is an object and unique (one-to-one), so..

I have two object **Car** with **Color** to one-to-one relationship.

```
public class Car
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public long ColorId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public long CarId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

I`m using Entity Framework, so for configuration used Fluent Api, and they look like as:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Color> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(k => k.Id);
            
    builder
        .HasOne(one => one.Car)
        .WithOne(with => with.Color)
        .HasForeignKey<Car>(fk => fk.CarId)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

In table i have **Car** with foreign key to **Color**, but foreign key in **Color** always **equals to** **0**. How i understand it`s correct mapping at one to one. In this case, I thought so be it, but later when I wanted to get **Car.Color** I saw that it always returns null. It`s not issue in adding, because followed up him in debugger.

In my opinion it`s issue in save or there's something I can't guess. This is based on the fact that on the path to save and even at the time of saving it has a reference (**Car.Color** = object), but when you first get it out of the database it is empty, similarly:

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Color": null,
    "ColorId": 3
}
```

Comment: Do you really want a `1:1` relationship between `Car` and `Color`? It seems reasonable that one car could be the same color as another.

Comment: @RufusL In general it was like a simplification of the example, in fact I use the **main user** and divided his **private** and **public information** into two classes which have their own instance in the **main user**. So I chose this solution because it seemed convenient to me, I'm curious to know how to do it better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code-First Entity Framework Relationship Always Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863659/code-first-entity-framework-relationship-always-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) part of EF Core docs. By default EF does not load the related data. There are multiple ways to handle that, for example using `Include`:

```cs
var carWithColor = await context.Car
   .Include(c => c.Color)
   .Where(c => c.Id == ...)
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

P.S.

Having one-to-one relationships between colors and cars seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: In general it was like a simplification of the example, in fact I use the main user and divided his private and public information into two classes which have their own instance in the main user. So I chose this solution because it seemed convenient to me, I'm curious to know how to do it better?